# Commonly liked posts by two users

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, relational-division

Given the following simplified models:

1. `User(id, nickname, created_at)`
2. `Post(id, user_id, image, text, created_at) ## A post belongs to a user`
3. `ViewedPost(id, user_id, post_id, like_type, created_at) ##like_type can either be -1, 0 or 1`

I would like to get the posts that were commonly liked (`like_type == 1`) by 2 different users (user1 and user2), sorted by `created_at`, according to user1.

Here is an example:

Given user1, user2, post1, post2, post3, post4 and the following scenario:

1. user1 likes (like_type: 1) post2, post3, then post1
2. user2 likes (like_type: 1) post4, post1, post2, then post3

The commonly liked posts are post1, post2, post3. Since I want this to be ranked according to user1 order of likes, it has to be post2, post3 then post1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A self-join on `ViewedPost` does the job. The rest is optimizing and formatting syntax:

```
SELECT post_id
FROM   ViewedPost v1
JOIN   ViewedPost v2 USING (post_id, like_type)
WHERE  v1.user_id = 1
AND    v2.user_id = 2
AND    like_type = 1
ORDER  BY v1.created_at;
```

Assuming a `UNIQUE` constraint in `ViewedPost` on `(user_id, post_id)`, so that the same user can only have *one* entry per post.

Comment: It worked perfectly. Is there any way I can do it using `Active Record`?